# Laravel project missing .env file

Tags: laravel, github, git-pull

I'm new to laravel and i recently pulled a project from git-hub and it wouldn't run because it's missing the .env file i tried composer install but that didn't work. Is there any other way to generate the .env file?

Comment: btw the idea of not having .env file on git, because it contains user sensitive information.

Answer (score 22):

You can download the standard [env.example](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example) file from the Laravel source code, rename it to `.env` and edit it. Just set up correct DB credentials, etc.

Don't forget to run the `php artisan key:generate` command which will generate an application (encryption) key and add it to the `.env` file.

Comment: I get that you can copy it from the source code off Laravels repo but everytime im cloning a project I must do this? I found a command but it doesn't seem to work, at least for me: ```copy .env.example .env``` it outputs ```zsh: command not found: copy``` into the terminal

Comment: @Eduardo `copy` command runs only in windows os. For zsh, use `cp`

Answer (score 4):

Just open an editor and create an .env file. Its a simple Text File.

And its ignored by git, because it contains sensitive data.

Edit: Normally there should be an .env.example file it the folder (which is not ignored by git by default), you can rename it to .env

Answer (score 2):

After running `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel` not all files are installed, including `.env.example`.

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/laravel/master/.env.example > .env
php artisan key:generate
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/laravel/master/.gitignore > .gitignore
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/laravel/master/.gitattributes > .gitattributes
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/laravel/master/.editorconfig > .editorconfig
```

`.gitignore` is important because it prevents the newly created `.env` from being commited.

Answer (score 2):

don't forget that .env is a hidden file, so you need to allow file explorer to "see" hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

1. Duplicate the Readme.md file in your project using your IDE
2. Edit the duplicate to .env
3. Copy content from [.env.example](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example)
4. Paste it in your .env file
5. Run `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: What's the point of duplicating the README.md, renaming it, and then replacing all of its contents? Couldn't one just create a new file with the desired contents?

Answer (score -2):

For me, it is invisible in VisualStudio too.
So I could not rename the `.env.example`, because it cause failed error duo to `.env` is already exist.
But I found it in windows explorer and opened it by NotePad to edit it.
I hope it works for you, too.